# Delegating `.on` is faster than bound `.on`?

Tags: jquery

Check out this test:

http://jsperf.com/delegate-on-vs-bind-5

What I did was delegate the child with a given parent and delegate another event to the child directly.  Testing (at least in Chrome) seems to indicate that the delegating method is *significantly* faster than the direct binding method.  This really goes against everything I've read about jQuery and also what I believe to be its intent.  Is my test mistaken or should we really just be using the delegation method?  Note that the parent is not even *that* close of an ancestor to the child.

This fiddle also confirms that the events are appropriately triggered with this DOM and JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/WtnRF/

Thoughts?

EDIT: To clarify, my specific question is why is the **delegation** method (traditionally supposed to be slower) so much faster than the **bind** method (supposed to be faster) in this test?

- Did I just write a bad test?
- Is jsperf benchmarking screwed up?
- Should we really just be using the **delegation** method all the time since it's superior?

Comment: Maybe `.click` just faster than `.blur`? :D

Comment: @neoascetic I reversed them now and the time difference is still about the same.

Comment: Perhaps because when you use the `.on` method the event doesn't bubble all the way up the DOM. It stops at the selector you provided when you created it (in your case `.thechild`).

Comment: @JasonTowne are you saying that since `.thechild` is already in the DOM that it can find it and bind to it immediately/directly?  In that case, why is it still so much faster than the regular `.bind` method?  They should be about the same.

Comment: Your test isn't very good. You're including DOM selection and logging in the test instead of just testing the trigger. And you're testing two different event types. I fixed your test, and direct binding is faster. http://jsperf.com/delegate-on-vs-bind-5/2

Comment: @JasonTowne: The event continues to bubble all the way up unless you stop it with `stopPropagation`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, My understanding is that when you call the `.on()` method with a selector as the second argument that puts a cap on how far the event will bubble up the DOM. By default, when an event is triggered it bubbles all the way up to the parent document. Your 'blur' delegate event stops at '.theChild'. Your 'click' event goes all the way up the DOM to the parent document.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity, True. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity you know, if you want to be respected you don't have to talk like "you're test isn't very *good*"  that said, I appreciate your change because it brings up an interesting point.  Apparently DOM selection for deeply nested elements takes significantly longer than for parents.  This is good to know.

Comment: I'm sorry if you were offended. I'm not at all worried about being direct. You asked the question *"Did I just write a bad test?"*. My answer is that the test is not very good. I didn't use any personally insulting language, but I did point out the fact and took the time to offer a more reasonable test. I would hope you'd be appreciative of that.

Comment: Honest question: Do you have more respect for one who upvotes the  question in spite of its flawed premise, lending support to it, or to someone who offers some clarity and truth, though perhaps without as much tact as you'd prefer?

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity I can tell you who I *don't* have respect for..

Comment: That's really too bad, since I'm the only one who took the time to explain something specific to your question.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity what do you want from me?  An upvote?  You didn't submit an answer.  You imply that the premise of my question is flawed too, but one of my specific questions was "is the test bad."  Wouldn't you want to upvote a question about a test that is wrong that has an answer that corrects it?  That's a great way to learn.

Comment: I don't care about votes. I see lots of upvotes happen on poor or incorrect answers/comments. I just meant that a +1 on your question isn't as useful as someone explaining the flaws in the test. Anyway, I don't want to argue with you. I really didn't mean to offend you in the first place. To add a little more value to my original comment, if I remember correctly, I think jQuery *may* have different fixes for the `blur` event, which is why it's important to test the same event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real answers will follow I'm sure, but you asked for thoughts.

My thought is that with modern systems it is Virtually Impossible to consistantly predict how a given construct will effect performance.

You will get the explanation for this one, and after thinking about it for a while and fiddling with it you will believe it (Or maybe it will be found to be a measuring error), but in the long run it won't give you any real insight into how to code better.  Furthermore on a different browser/platform/version/day of the week it will happen to work differently.

The problem is that if there is a construct they expect you to use a lot (because that's how people generally code), they will optimize it first and it will probably perform faster.  The results of this is that the performance improvements done at the levels beneath your code will typically improve your well-written code over code your hand-optimized code.

This means you should NEVER code for performance, code for clarity and DRY, period.  If you do so and hit a barrier where some customer or manager judges it too slow (Get Performance Requirements!), then consider recoding it with before-and-after measurements on each platform of course.  Do comparisions and ensure that the "Optimized" solution is actually worth the lack of clarity and actually meets the requiremetns.  Document WHY you did this in the code so someone else doesn't come along and fix what looks like your crappy coding style later.